# Linux Mint: Permamente measured values CPU as Sensor App?

Tags: linux, linux-mint

I would like to have the processor temperature displayed within Linux Mint. Currently I only have the sensor command which shows the actual temperature but does not offer a permanent monitoring.

Currently I use the sensor command inside the terminal: sensors

Question: But how can I have a permanent monitoring, preferably as desktop APP as display?

Does anyone have any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install an applet `CPU Temperature Indicator`.

After installing open terminal and write `sensors`. Then push `enter`.

Shutdown and reboot your computer and it should show correct temperature.

It works for me with amd-ryzen 7 linux mint 20.